# how can i draw a growing line effect in mpandroidchart (Animation)?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

how can i growing line android effect in MPAndroidChart, I want to continuously graph animation.

like this:

[image]

```
float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

    mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet);

    cubicPath.reset();

    if (mXBounds.range >= 1) {

        Entry prev = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(mXBounds.min);
        Entry cur = prev;

        // let the spline start
        cubicPath.moveTo(cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);

        for (int j = mXBounds.min + 1; j <= mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min; j++) {

            prev = cur;
            cur = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

            final float cpx = (prev.getX())
                    + (cur.getX() - prev.getX()) / 2.0f;

            cubicPath.cubicTo(
                    cpx, prev.getY() * phaseY,
                    cpx, cur.getY() * phaseY,
                    cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
        }
    }

    // if filled is enabled, close the path
    if (dataSet.isDrawFilledEnabled()) {

        cubicFillPath.reset();
        cubicFillPath.addPath(cubicPath);
        // create a new path, this is bad for performance
        drawCubicFill(mBitmapCanvas, dataSet, cubicFillPath, trans, mXBounds);
    }

    mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());

    mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    trans.pathValueToPixel(cubicPath);

    mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, mRenderPaint);

    mRenderPaint.setPathEffect(null);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [Animations](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Animations).

It might be enough to just use something like:

`mChart.animateX(3000);`

Furthermore you can choose one of many predefined animations called `EasingOption` to achieve a non-linear animation.

Comment: Hey guys,

I have one LineChart with x-axis going from 1 to 5 (y does not matter here) but when I call chart.animateX(1000) it animates exactly as in your demo app, i other words:

line between 1 and 2 just show up
line between 2 and 3 just show up
and son on

I just wanna help implement a better behavior, drawing the line smoothly from point 1 to 2, from 2 to 3 etc.

Any guidance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mLineChart.animateX(1750, Easing.EasingOption.Linear);
```